# GSM SIM card pin code recovery

Tags: 3g

I'd like to reinstall a ubuntu laptop that has working WWAN, but I lost the pin code of the SIM card.

Since Ubuntu uses the sim card fine, I'm assuming that it has the pin code written somewhere in a config file ...

How to see the SIM card pin code that ubuntu has kept in configuration ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Click the network icon in the top-right of the screen and choose "Edit connections...". Now, open the "Mobile broadband" tab, select the connection of your choice and click "Edit". You will be able to find this information in the window that opens.